# Cmake using compiled OpenCV version

Tags: c, opencv, cmake

I compiled the `opencv-2.4.13` version, and now I want to compile a project using cmake.

If I do:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(phase)
find_package(Opencv REQUIRED)
include_directories(INCLUDE_DIR include)
aux_source_directory(src SOURCE)
add_library(dct SHARED src/dct.c ${SOURCE}
```

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpencv.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Opencv", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Opencv" with any
  of the following names:

    OpencvConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Opencv" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Opencv_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Opencv"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

So I created a folder named `cmake-modules` and copied the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file generated by the compiled OpenCV project.

Then:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(phase)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules)
find_package(Opencv REQUIRED)
include_directories(INCLUDE_DIR include)
aux_source_directory(src SOURCE)
add_library(dct SHARED src/dct.c ${SOURCE})
```

But I still getting the same error.

How do I should include the `.cmake` file to find OpenCV?

Comment: What is wrong with error message? It suggest you either: 1. To adjust `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` for contain `FindOpencv.cmake` script **or** 2. Adjust `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or `Opencv_DIR` for find `OpencvConfig.cmake`. But you adjust `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` for find `OpenCVConfig.cmake`... BTW, correct package name to search is `find_package(OpenCV)`, case is meaningfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(phase)
SET(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/facu/opencv-2.4.13/include/opencv")
include_directories(INCLUDE_DIR include ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(OpenCV_LIB_DIR "/home/facu/opencv-2.4.13/release/lib")
link_directories(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})
aux_source_directory(src SOURCE)
add_library(dct SHARED src/dct.c ${SOURCE})
```